# Similarity measures and conditional probabilities

Tags: correlation, conditional-probability, association-measure

In the article [Measures for Binary Data](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_proximities_measures_binary_data.htm) from the SPSS knowledge base, one reads:

> The following binary measures [K2, SS4, HAMANN] yield values that can
>   be interpreted in terms of conditional probability. All three measures
>   are similarity measures.

I wonder how similarity measures and conditional probability are related in general? Is there more than "A can be interpreted in terms of B"? What have they to do with each other?

Is it for example true, that when (any) similarity or correlation is 0 then $p(X|Y) = p(X)$ and vice versa? Does this hold for all similarity measures? Are there more advanced quantitative relationships?

**EDIT:**

With $p(X|Y) = \frac{a}{a+c}$ and $p(Y|X) = \frac{a}{a+b}$ and $\mathsf{HAMANN}(X,Y) := \frac{(a+d) - (b+c)}{a+b+c+d} = 0$ iff $a+d = b+c$ one can conclude

When $\mathsf{HAMANN}(X,Y) = 0$ then $\frac{p(X|Y)}{p(Y|X)} = \frac{2c + b - d}{2b + c - d}$. This seems not to be a very strong restriction, it seems not even obvious that it is stronger than the general restriction

$$\frac{p(X|Y)}{p(Y|X)} = \frac{a + b}{a + c} = \frac{p(X)}{p(Y)},$$

or is it? (It should be.)

Does this mean, that there is no (strong) relationship between correlation and conditional probability? (Why should we only consider the quotient $p(X|Y)/p(Y|X)$, we could also consider $|p(X|Y)-p(Y|X)|$.)

Comment: You simply look at the formulas of the document, and meditate over their consequences, keeping in mind that P(X|Y)= a/(a+c), P(Y|X)= a/(a+b).

Comment: That's exactly what I just came up with ("by accident"). But what does meditation tell me?